# Transposición columnar de 3 columnas en Java

Tags: java, array, test, junit

Quisiera crear mediante dos métodos no estáticos, una clase que cifre y descifre una cadena.

```
public String cifra(String cadena){
        String resultado = "";
        if(cadena == null | cadena.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            "..."
        }
        return resultado;

}
```

```
public String descifrar(String cadena) {
        String resultado = "";
        if(cadena == null | cadena.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            "..."
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

El mensaje a cifrar hay que dividirlo en 3 columnas y el cifrado tiene que ser el resultado de leer las 3 columnas de arriba hacia abajo. Esa cadena habría que pasarla a matriz de char [][] y recorrer la matriz por columnas para cifrar y por filas para descifrar.

Por ejemplo:

Cadena = “EL_CIELO_ES_AZUL_COMO_EL_MAR” La tabla que se generaría para la codificación seria tal que así:

EL_

CIE

LO_

ES_

AZU

L_C

OMO

_EL

_MA

R__

Resultado de cifrado: ECLEALO__RLIOSZ_MEM__E__UCOLA_

Tengo que comprobarlo mediante Test con JUnit tanto el cifrado como descifrado.

```
    //Test de Cifrados
    @Test
    void testCifrar1() {
   
        String resultadoActual = transcolumnar.cifra("LA_LLUVIA_EN_SEVILLA_ES_UNA_MARAVILLA");
        String resultadoEsperado = "LLV__VLEU_RIAALIESIASNMAL__UANEL__AAVL";
        
        assertEqueals(resultadoActual, resultadoEsperado);
    }
```

¿Cómo tendría que hacer los métodos para poder recorrer la cadena y cifrarlos?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tendria 3 arrays (Columna 1,Columna 2,Columna 3) recorrería la cadena a cifrar e iria poniendo secuencialmente.

```
List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> array3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<cadenaACifrar.length();i++){
    if (i % 3 == 0){ //Inserto en el primer array
        array1.add()
    } else if (i % 3 == 1){//Inserto en el segundo array
        array2.add()
    } else { //Inserto en el tercer array
        array3.add()
    }
}
String cadenaCifrada = array1 + array2 + array3; //Deberias recorrer los arrays e insertarlos en cadenaCifrada
```

El if interno se puede cambiar por un switch, los array se puede hacer un array de arrays y parametrizar la cantidad de columnas. En fin son detalles de optimizacion y configurabilidad, pero solo si te interesa mejorar el codigo.

Tambien intenta como minimo publicar un codigo de que has hecho algo de logica para que te podamos ayudar con mas especificidad, el codigo que te di es un pseudocodigo en Java el cual tendras que desarrollar, supongo que tendras los conocimientos para hacerlo.

Comment: Pero y si quiero meterlo en un array bidimensional, es decir, char [][] cadenaCifrada = new char[nFilas][3] ¿?

Comment: Deberias llevar un contador de la fila actual en la que deberias insertar:
for (int i=0;i<cadenaACifrar.length();i++){
    int fila = 0;
    if (i % 3 == 0){ //Inserto en la primer columna
        array1.add()
    } else if (i % 3 == 1){//Inserto en la segunda columna
        array2.add()
    } else { //Inserto en la tercer columna y aumento la fila en la que deberia insertar
        array3.add();
        fila++;
    }
}

Comment: for (int i=0;i<cadenaACifrar.length();i++){
   char[][] matBidim= new char[nFilas][3];
    int fila = 0;
    if (i % 3 == 0){ //Inserto en la primer columna
        matBidim[fila][1]
    } else if (i % 3 == 1){//Inserto en la segunda columna
        matBidim[fila][2]
    } else { //Inserto en la tercer columna y aumento la fila en la que deberia insertar
        matBidim[fila][3]
        fila++;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Hola mi respuesta a esta pregunta es, mejor use un método de encriptación un poco mas fácil de realizar pero mas eficiente en lugar de intercambiar las letras, pero si quiere hacerlo así siga leyendo... (o copie y pegue el final)

Entrada de texto antes de cifrar: `"EL_CIELO_ES_AZUL_COMO_EL_MAR"`

Salida una vez cifrado: `"CLEEO_EI_LZ_LSCAMU__LOMOREA_"`

Salida una vez descifrado: `"EL_CIELO_ES_AZUL_COMO_EL_MAR"`

--------------- EXPLICACIÓN --------------

Primero que nada necesita un método `cifrar()` y otro `descifrar()`, en el método `cifrar();` pasara por parámetro la cadena a "cifrar", este devolverá la matriz una vez cifrada.

Dentro de este método se creara la matriz bidimensional de 'x' filas por 3 columnas, las filas las obtenemos por tantos caracteres que tenga la cadena, creamos primero este array de `char[]` llamado "caracteres" con el método `toCharArray()` que devuelve todos los caracteres que tiene la cadena.

Luego iremos recorriendo con un for este array unidimensional que creamos llamado "caracteres", antes de comenzar con el bucle `for` creamos otro array pero bidimensional de `char[][]` con `caracteres.lenght` de filas y columnas 3 que son los que desea, llamado "partes" (por ponerle nombre)

Creamos variables contadoras de `int columns = 0, row = 0;`

Y comenzamos con el for, este recorrerá el primer array llamado "caracteres" y comprobara si la columna que esta recorriendo es `[2]` que es igual a 3 en el array, si es así, establecemos `columns = 0;` y `rows++;`

Agregamos los caracteres al array bidimensional `char[][]` que lo llamamos "partes" de esta manera:

```
partes[row][columns] = caracteres[i];
```

De esta manera ira agregando los caracteres en la fila y columna actual de el array "caracteres" `[i]` luego hacemos un `columns++;` para ir avanzando en columnas.

Al final del método retornamos `return desordenar(partes);` este método lo único que hace intercambiar la posición de los caracteres `[][]` algo así como el método burbuja pero solo una vez, hacia adelante.

Para volver a descifrar la cadena, únicamente tiene que usar el método de cifrar, seria algo así como una "CARTA" que de un lado esta cifrado pero del otro no, y tenes que darla vuelta para volver a ver lo que dice.

Acá el método cifrar:

```
// CREA UN ARRAY BIDIMENCIONAL DE 3 COLUMNAS
// CON LOS (char) QUE TIENE LA CADENA

// EL CARÁCTER '\u0000' LA REPRESENTACIÓN DE NULO, PERO NO LO ES

private char[][] cifrar(String cadena) {
    char[] caracteres = cadena.toCharArray();       
    
    char[][] partes = new char[caracteres.length][3];
    
    int columns = 0, row = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++) {
        if(columns == 2) {
            columns = 0;
            row++;
        }
        
        partes[row][columns] = caracteres[i];
        //System.out.println(partes[row][columns]);
        
        columns++;
    }
    
    // UNA VEZ CREADO EL ARRAY LO DESORDENAMOS Y RETORNAMOS
    return desordenar(partes); 
}
```

Método desordenar:

```
// DESORDENAR: CONSISTE EN INTERCAMBIAR LA POSICIÓN DE LOS CARACTERES,
// ALGO ASÍ COMO EL MÉTODO BURBUJA

// EL CARACTER '\u0000' ES EL EQUIVALENTE A NULO, PERO NO ES NULO

private char[][] desordenar(char[][] array) {
    int columns = 0;
    int row = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(columns == 2) {
            columns = 0;
            row++;
        }
        
        if(array[row+1][columns+1] != '\u0000') {
            char c = array[row][columns]; 
            array[row][columns] = array[row+1][columns+1];
            array[row+1][columns+1] = c;
        }

        columns++;
    }
    
    return array;
}
```

Y el método ordenar:

```
// PARA ORDENARLO SIMPLEMENTE LO VOLVEMOS A DESORDENAR
private char[][] ordenar(char[][] array) {
    return desordenar(array);
}
```

Antes de que te vayas es importante decir que si quiere imprimir el array de una vez ordenado o desordenado no le va a funcional de la manera normal, que seria utilizando doble bucle for, esto no lo entendí muy bien cuando lo estaba programando, me canse de intentar y de ahí salio el contador de `row and columns` con un solo bucle for, que he estado usando para esto.

Si sabe adaptar esto para que funcione de la manera normal utilizando doble bucle for, ahorrara un montón de lineas de código y eficiencia me imagino, yo no lo puede y me canse entonces lo hice como puede, que igualmente funciona.

Metodo de imprmir:

```
// IMPRIME EL ARRAY BIDIMENCIONAL, DE LA MISMA FORMA
// EN LA QUE SE CREO, SI LO TRATA DE RECORRER CON DOBLE BUCLE FOR
// NO MOSTRARA LOS CARACTERES CORRECTAMENTE. (SORPRESA)

private void printArray(char[][] array) {
    int columns = 0; // C
    int row = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(columns == 2) {
            columns = 0;
            row++;
        }
        
        System.out.print(array[row][columns]);
        
        columns++;
    }
    
    System.out.println("");
    
}
```